# ¿En qué momento se pasa la dirección de memoria y el valor?

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo esta estructura que me dieron de ejemplo

```
typedef struct nodoPila{
    int entry; 
    struct nodoPila *ptrSiguiente; /** Apuntador al siguiente nodo*/
}NodoPila;

typedef NodoPila *ptrNodoPila;

/** Prototipos */

//void createStack(ptrNodoPila);
void push(ptrNodoPila*, int);
int pop(ptrNodoPila*);
bool stackEmpty(ptrNodoPila);
void printStack(ptrNodoPila);
void delStack(ptrNodoPila*);
```

No entiendo muy bien en qué momento se está haciendo el paso por valor y el paso por referencia.

Tengo los métodos funcionando, solo necesito que me expliquen como funcionan:

```
/** Insertar un nuevo nodo */
void push(ptrNodoPila *ptrCima, int entry){
    ptrNodoPila ptrNuevo; /** Apuntador al nuevo nodo */
    ptrNuevo = malloc(sizeof(NodoPila));
    /** Inserta el nuevo nodo encima de la pila */
    if(ptrNuevo != NULL){
        ptrNuevo -> entry = entry;
        ptrNuevo -> ptrSiguiente = *ptrCima;
        *ptrCima = ptrNuevo;
    }else{
        printf("%d No se inserto. Memoria insuficiente. \n",entry);
    }
}
/** Devuelve true si la pila esta vacia, de lo contrario false */
bool  stackEmpty(ptrNodoPila ptrCima){
    return ptrCima == NULL;
}
/** Eliminar un nodo de la cima de la pila */
int pop(ptrNodoPila *ptrCima){
    ptrNodoPila ptrTemp; /** Apuntador a un nodo temporal */
    int valorElim; /* Valor del nodo */

    ptrTemp = *ptrCima;
    valorElim = ( *ptrCima )-> entry;
    *ptrCima = ( *ptrCima ) -> ptrSiguiente;
    free(ptrTemp);
    return valorElim;
}
```

Este es parte del main....

```
int main(){
int se =3;
/** Apunta al tope de la pila */
ptrNodoPila ptrPila = NULL;

/** Inserta un elemento */
push(&ptrPila,se);

/**Elimina un elemento*/
if(stackEmpty(ptrPila))
    printf("\n << La pila esta vacia >>\n");
else{ 
    int aux = pop(&ptrPila);
    printf("\n<<< Dato retirado: %d >>>\n",aux);
}
```

Comment: Dirás paso por referencia, no paso por parámetros.

Comment: Hola! ¿podrías aclarar un poco más que es lo que no entiendes?

Comment: Por ejemplo cuando tengo el metodo     void push(ptrNodoPila*, int)   ¿Qué es lo que estoy recibiendo? la dirección a la estructura o la estructura en sí, y como podría tratarla en el metodo al ejecutarlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef NodoPila* ptrNodoPila;
```

La línea anterior indica que `ptrNodoPila` es un puntero. Por definición si pasas como parámetro un puntero estás usando referencias ya que el puntero es en sí mismo una referencia.

Otra cosa es si el puntero lo pasas por valor o por referencia. La diferencia entre un uso u otro es bastante clara:

- Si pasas un puntero por valor podrás modificar únicamente la información referenciada por dicho puntero.
- Si pasas un puntero por referencia podrás hacer que el puntero apunte a otra dirección de memoria además de modificar la información referenciada.

¿Cómo saber si un puntero se pasa por valor o por referencia? Es muy fácil como vas a ver a continuación. Para entenderlo vamos a tratar inicialmente con un tipo sencillo como un `int`:

```
void func1(int variable) // por valor
{
  variable=1;
}
void func2(int* variable) // por referencia
{
  *variable=2;
}

int main()
{
  int var = 0;
  func1(var);
  printf("%d ", var); // 0, pues func1 recibe una copia de var
  func2(&var);
  printf("%d ", var); // 2, pues func2 recibe una referencia a var
}
```

Como vemos para pasar una variable por referencia hay que usar un puntero simple. ¿Qué sucede con los punteros simples?

```
void func1(int* variable) // por valor
{
  variable = 1;
}
void func2(int** variable) // por referencia
{
  *variable = 2;
}

int main()
{
  int *ptr = 0;
  func1(ptr);

  // Nota que vamos a imprimir la dirección de memoria a la que apunta
  printf("%d ", ptr); // 0, pues func1 recibe una copia de ptr
  func2(&ptr);
  printf("%d ", ptr); // 2, pues func2 recibe una referencia a ptr
}
```

Parece que el patrón es claro. Para que un tipo concreto se pase como referencia hay que añadir un nivel de indirección, es decir, para un tipo normal hay que usar un puntero simple, para un puntero simple uno doble, para un puntero doble necesitamos uno triple, ...

Ahora volviendo a tu código:

```
// El primer parámetro es un puntero doble, ya que ptrNodoPila es un puntero
// El segundo parámetro se pasa por valor
void push(ptrNodoPila*, int);

// El parámetro es un puntero doble
int pop(ptrNodoPila*);

// En los siguientes, parámetro es un puntero simple
bool stackEmpty(ptrNodoPila);
void printStack(ptrNodoPila);

// Y esta función vuelve a trabajar con un puntero doble
void delStack(ptrNodoPila*);
```

Un saludo.

Comment: ¡Excelente! No había pasado por mi mente que se estaba haciendo uso de punteros simples y dobles, muchas gracias!